# How do I sort card objects by their id

Tags: c#, sorting

Suppose I have a hand (list) of 8 card objects, the cards are unordered. Each card object in the deck has an id from 1 to 52. but the deck is shuffled then 8 cards are dealt to me. Here are the things I have access to:

```
hand // a list of 8 card objects
hand[0].GetCardId() // returns the id of first card in my hand
```

Having these two things, how do you sort my hand so that the first card in my hand has the smallest id and the last card in my hand has the biggest id?

Comment: `var sortedHand = hand.OrderBy(card => card.GetCardId()).ToList();`

Comment: this sounds like an excercise. How are you supposed to sort it? are you allowed to use LINQ? or are you supposed to learn how to use loops to implement the sorting yourself?

Comment: @MongZhu No I'm just creating a card game and to add a new functionality, I need the cards in the hand of the player to be ordered in a specific way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> sort my hand so that the first card in my hand has the smallest id and
> the last card in my hand has the biggest id?

With LINQ

```
hand.OrderBy(c => c.GetCardId());
```

With Array class

```
Array.Sort(hand, (a, b) => a.GetCardId() - b.GetCardId());
```

Comment: that did it for me `hand = hand.OrderBy(c => c.GetCardId()).ToList();`